# Python format floating point number to fixed TOTAL width

Tags: python, floating-point, format

How can I format a floating point number to always have the same **total** number of digits?

For example, 5 digits:

```
.123456
1.2
12.34
```

would become

```
0.1234
1.2000
12.340
```

I have found solutions to limiting precision, padding zeroes, etc. but nothing that gives a fixed width for the whole number (not just left or right sides).

Comment: Just to clarify your question: let's suppose that your fixed width is 5 and that your number is 67881234.61. What would you expect to get?

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince for my application, I know the numbers will never be larger than 1000, i.e., there will always be at least one decimal place.

Comment: I think they shouldn't have closed your question, because I think your requirements were slightly different than the question they point as the duplicate. Anyway, here's a way of doing it: -> `str(your_float_number).ljust(6, '0')[:6]`

Comment: @revliscano I agree, the other question doesn't address the need to add trailing zeros.  If you're quick you can add your proposed solution as an answer.

Comment: @MatthewSalvatoreViglione Is it what you really expect that 0.123456 is printed as 0.1234, not 0.1235 (so you expect truncating to zero instead of default rounding to nearest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested you in the comments, you can start by transforming the float number to a string object, and from there you can use the `ljust()` method of the `str` class, and string slicing.

Something as follows:

```py
# Define a function that returns the desired output
format_f = lambda x: str(x + .0).ljust(6, '0')[:6]
# Let's iterate over the float numbers your provided as example
for float_ in .123456, 1.2, 12.34:
    # You can call the function like in the below line
    print(format_f(float_))
```

**output**

```
0.1234
1.2000
12.340
```

Comment: Doesn't work for integers, but that didn't appear to be a requirement.

Comment: I fixed it to work for integers too by first casting the input to a float: `str(float(x)).ljust(6, "0")[:6]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You're right. Updating the answer now to accept integers. @MarkRansom